# HNQ logos showing up incorrectly

Tags: bug, status-norepro, design, hot-questions

Not sure if you're aware, but the **site logos in the Hot Network Questions bar are displaying incorrectly**. See the image below:

[image: Screen capture depicting incorrect logos on HNQ bar]

1. [**Secret salts; why do they slow down attacker more than they do me?**](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/144536/44739)
   Is actually on the [Information Security](https://security.stackexchange.com/) site, yet it's displaying a different "beta" logo.
2. [**Can a creature with 0 power attack?**](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/q/33276)
   Is actually a question on the [Board & Card Games <sup>beta</sup>](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/) site, yet it's displaying with a different site's logo
3. [**Unable to complete a task at work. How should I tell my employer?**](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/80900/18317)
   Is actually from the [The Workplace](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/) site, yet it's displaying a logo from the [Webmasters](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) site

**What is going on?**

Comment: Aaaaaand it's gone. I'll blame it on cache. Can't reproduce rhe issue.

Comment: possible related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/339132/everything-is-3d