# Wrong icons in the "hot network questions" column

Tags: bug, status-completed, global-inbox, hot-questions, logo

Currently the "hot networks" column is showing wrong icons for some, but not all of the sites. (The URLs linked to have the correct site).

It seems to happen only on some sites -- I see it on Mathematics and Travel but not here, for example. It happens both in Firefox and Chrome for me. This screenshot is from the math.SE homepage in a fresh Chrome session. I don't usually use Chrome to access SE, so I doubt it is something getting stuck in a browser cache.

[image: Screenshot]

The icons for Academia, Ask Ubuntu and Ask Different are right, but *"Why doesn't Cersei make peace with Jon Snow"* is definitely not a Music question. Neither is *"Why did Neo even have to fight?"* really about Information Security ... hmm, it might be, but the actual question is on Scifi.

It also affects the navigation and global inbox dropdowns, when I view them on a site that has the problem.

The site's actual favicon is *not* affected.

Comment: And questions about indicating interest in going places isn't IoT... Probably IPS... Weird bug

Comment: Server caching insanity... it [happens](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/287854/hnq-logos-showing-up-incorrectly) sometimes, always fixing itself soon after.

Comment: Needs [freehand circles](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19775/353213).

Comment: Is it still happening? We kicked the CDN caches a while ago, but I never saw the out of order icons, so it's hard to confirm the fix.

Comment: Is it just me or is that the old SO logo?

Comment: @AdamLear It is still happening. Currently the following has wrong icons: Board & Card games, English language and usage, Italian language, Role-playing games (you can check yourself by opening the all sites dropdown). Interestingly, Meta Stack Overflow has the wrong icon too [when viewed from the dropdown on Stack Overflow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I6qmK.png), but has the right icon [when viewed from dropdown on Meta SO itself](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rlYbA.png).

Comment: @AdamLear: Still happening for me too, freshly booted machine.

Comment: [Same...](https://image.prntscr.com/image/_9rI6dLVTce1t--xfst2wQ.png), and this is post-cookie clearing, on multiple systems (4 out of 4 different Windows machines).

Comment: If you go to https://cdn.sstatic.net/img/favicons-sprite16.png?v=0b5182b5ddfc (and zoom in :)), do you see the `Aug` favicon? The list is sorta alphabetical by site, so it should be in the top part of the image, right below Ask Ubuntu and A for Astronomy. (cc @GhotiandChips)

Comment: @AdamLear: Curiouser and curiouser: I don't see `Aug` when I click on the link in Firefox (and then save the image), but when I copy the URL and download with `wget` instead, it is there just above Aviation ... I suppose an old version could be stuck in Firefox's cache (though I have cleared that several times), but then why am I only seeing wrong icons on _some_ of the sites?

Comment: @AdamLear If I'm supposed to see a black version of the Astronomy favicon, then yes.

Comment: @GhotiandChips: The correct image has blue `A`, black `A`, blue `Aug`, black `Aug`, red Aviation, black Aviation.

Comment: `curl` downloads the correct image; Chrome and IE both download the old one without `Aug`. The browser behavior is unaffected by Ctrl-F5.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Then, no. No Aug for me.

Comment: Using Chrome on all my systems, this issue crops up for all.

Comment: Ah, I see. `meta.stackexchange.com` alone among all the sites seems to load the favicons image from its own domain (which works for me), whereas all other sites I've tried use `cdn.sstatic.net` (and don't work for me).

Comment: Flashget also downloads a file with `Aug`. No `Aug` in all browsers I have. @AdamLear

Comment: @AdamLear: Following more testing, I get the wrong version of the image with wget if and only if I send an `Accept-Encoding: gzip` header in the HTTP request.

Comment: Incidentally, the response does not actually have a Content-Encoding in either case, but it does say `Vary: Accept-Encoding`. It's probably not the cache's fault, because I get the same when I put `Accept-Encoding: deflate,crunch,squeeze,gzip` -- but not when I give value that doesn't include `gzip`.

Comment: @HenningMakholm We purged the cache again. Did that help?

Comment: @AdamLear: Yes, looks like it.

Comment: @AdamLear I took [this screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/PvTYQ1k.png) 15 minutes ago (with my writing saying what site it really links to). So if it was gone then it's back now. I've seen it a lot these last few days. This specific one was on physics meta, on [this question](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10058/is-an-askers-age-relevant?cb=1).

Comment: It's strange, but it seems like almost all of the mistakes gets a new icon from a site with the same first letter in its name: SciFi / Security, Math / Math Educators, Retrocomputing / Reverse engineering, History / Homebrewing, Skeptics / Software engineering, TeX / ToR, Mathematica / Meta.math, Movies / Music, Money / Movies. Does it just take the next icon over from what it should?

Comment: [Code Golf thread.](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13556/site-icons-being-messed-up)

Comment: @Arthur: Yes, it picks logos at the _right_ place from an _old_ sheet of logos (see the link Adam Lear posted above), so what it displays is mostly off-by-one according to the mostly-alphabetic order.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem seems to have been fixed now after @Adam Lear purged the cache.

Comment: It's back. I took [this screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/PvTYQ1k.png) 15 minutes ago. It's happened to me several times these last days.

Comment: [Encountered the same:](http://i.imgur.com/L9E6ECC.png) Workplace > Worldbuilding icon, Worldbuilding > Default W, SciFi > Security, and so on. Either opening the favicon sprite png or a hard refresh resolved it.

Comment: @Arthur: Does hard-refreshing (ctrl-F5 in most browsers) help? Have you seen it work _correctly_ (on the same machine) _after_ Adam Lear wrote that he purged the cache?

Comment: @HenningMakholm I hadn't been on that exact question before that time, but it's still there, and a refresh didn't help, although of course, the exact list of questions has changed since then. [This](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10058/is-an-askers-age-relevant?cb=1) is the page I screengrabbed from.

Comment: @Arthur: Which precise page you're viewing doesn't matter (if it is the same bug recurring). But it _does_ matter whether you do a normal refresh (F5) or a hard refresh (Ctrl-F5). If even hard-refreshing doesn't help, try loading https://cdn.sstatic.net/img/favicons-sprite16.png?v=0b5182b5ddfc which Adam Lear linked to and hard-refreshing _that_.

Comment: Oh, hard refresh is something different, I see. Yes, that helped.

Comment: @HenningMakholm I'm seeing this happen now.  I've tried hard-refreshing, but the issue continues.