# Incorrect site icons on Hot Network Questions

Tags: bug, hot-questions, logo

The questions listed under Hot Network Questions each have a little icon representing their exchange (a "P" for "Parenting", a speech bubble for "Meta", etc.) -- but recently these icons are all mixed up! For instance, a question from "Outdoors" might have the piggy-bank icon from "Money" on it. This is only for some exchanges, though (I haven't compiled a list of affected sites).

**Who do I tell, if not you guys?**

In Meta and Parenting, it seems to be working:

[image]

In UX, Workplace, and stackoverflow.com, it's broken:

[image]

Comment: [The bug was reported recently](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/299205/312043) and Adam Lear confirmed that it was fixed, looks like not yet fixed.

Comment: @Lilienthal I don't think it should be a dupe. [Share your idea](/q/299286/), please.

Comment: Does it help to load and then hard-refresh (Ctrl-F5) https://cdn.sstatic.net/img/favicons-sprite16.png?v=0b5182b5ddfc ?

Comment: Yes, it seems to do the trick -- so it _is_ fixed, just also cached. Thank you!