# What to do if a bug that was claimed to be fixed still persists?

Tags: discussion, bug-reports

[*Adam Lear* ♦ claimed that this bug was fixed yesterday](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/299205/revisions), and [it seems to still persist](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/299281). Someone suggested that the newer post be a duplication, but I don't agree with that. I know this is a <s>rare</s> uncommon case, yet I'm curious about the community's idea.

Possible reasons that may re-create a similar case:

- [A dirty fix](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/299205/a#comment972613_299205) was performed, and wrong content keeps being generated by faulty programs.
- An old, *really*-fixed bug is re-introduced somehow.

This post should be useful for all the cases above

Comment: While it's still fresh, just post a comment on the answer by the developer, or if no answer  comment-reply on the question, since as editor they will be pingable. If no response is given after a while, better submit new bug report and explain what happened. I think this was already discussed before, no time to search ATM though.

Comment: Leave a comment to the question.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Haha. No dupe on MSE but I found this on MSO: [What to do when a meta post is marked as status-completed, but not fixed in reality?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260567)

Answer (score 5):

I agree with [Shadow Wizard's comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/299286/what-to-do-if-a-bug-that-was-claimed-to-be-fixed-still-persists#comment972889_299286); ping the relevant Stack Overflow developer/employee who indicated that the bug has been solved, but only if it's reasonably 'fresh'.

Sometimes, completed bug reports are (wrongly) closed with the following reason:

> The problem described here can no longer be reproduced. Changes to the system or to the circumstances affecting the asker have rendered it obsolete. *If you encounter a similar problem, please post a new question.*

<sub>(emphasis mine)</sub>

While that isn't the case here, it *does* indicate that it's perfectly normal to create a new bug report if a bug resurfaces after a while.