# Stack Exchange site icons displaying incorrectly in Hot Network Questions

Tags: bug, hot-questions

The same as [Incorrect site icons on Hot Network Questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/299281/incorrect-site-icons-on-hot-network-questions) from August 2017. Most site icons are displaying incorrectly in Hot Network Questions. Not on Meta, but on most other sites.

Compare the icons for "How do I convey that I am bad at remembering things?" from Meta (left) and ELL (right):

[image]
[image]

I've tried doing a hard refresh but I'm still seeing the incorrect icons.

Comment: There was a new site added today ([Bioacoustics](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/126698/bioacoustics)) so it may take a few days before all the icon caches are synced (server-side) and the correct icons are displayed again.

Comment: no-repro from me

Comment: @Luuklag I'm still seeing it after another hard refresh. It could be that we are on different mirrors.

Comment: I'm seeing the phenomenon in the all communities drop-down list from the top bar, even after a hard refresh.

Comment: Three days later and it's still happening. I think something is broken.

Comment: Have y'all seen this happen again since then?