# Favicon sprites are offset in site list dropdown, not as a result of a new site being created

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, favicon

I opened up the site today and am seeing site favicons offset in a weird way:

[image: Site favicons in dropdown list are offset]

Is this just me? Or did something happen with the way the sprites are rendered?

The Featured sidebar is where I noticed this first:

[image: Site sprites for Meta Stack Exchange are offset in the Feature sidebar]

Using Chrome 103.0.5060.134 on Windows 10 on a corporate network.

Comment: Mechanics site theme was just launched a bit ago, so it may be related to that - checking. :) I see it in the site selector and in the [HNQ list on the right rail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JXAf9.png).

Comment: +1 for having Stack Apps in "Your  Communities"

Comment: It's happening to me too on `Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:103.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/103.0`

Comment: Same problem on ELU.

Comment: It's also broken in the inbox. Strangely enough, Teams is the only one not broken

Comment: The file is called [favicons-sprite16.png](https://meta.stackexchange.com/Content/Img/favicons-sprite16.png?v=bafa22065134), but it's 17 pixels wide. Might that have something to do with it?

Comment: The icons are all stored in [one long thin image](https://cdn.sstatic.net/Img/favicons-sprite16.png) which is re-positioned in multiples of 16 pixels to bring each icon into a 16x16 space. However, the current version of that image is 7038 pixels high - which is not a multiple of 16! It is, however, a multiple of **17**. I suspect a new icon was added that is 17x17 instead of 16x16, and the script generating the combined "spritemap" has padded all the others to match, throwing off all the offsets.

Comment: No repro, chrome on android

Comment: @Luuklag I think that's probably caching. Can you repro in private browsing mode?

Comment: The [32 pixel spritemap](https://cdn.sstatic.net/Img/favicons-sprite32.png) looks to also be affected: it is 414*34 pixels high, rather than 414*32.

Comment: No repro in incognito either @wizzwizz4

Comment: Same problem on all sites I've tried in Firefox on Wayland on Arch Linux. Not in private mode; I've definitely visited SE before today

Comment: I'm a little curious, though; I'd've expected the offset to be the other way, if the problem were that the image was too wide. Arduino's favicon's currently its meta site, for example.

Comment: Also happening in the HNQ sidebar. Gives some communities the wrong icons, the Unix site now has the Writing icon!

Comment: Broken here as well.  Kinda surprised about how this came about, too.

Comment: It is [not just you](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NpxQB.png). (Microsoft edge on W10 and mozilla firefox)

Comment: If I zoom in to 150%+ it fixes itself.

Comment: @Warcupine same for me

Comment: @Warcupine oh, above 150% it uses a different file: https://meta.stackexchange.com/Content/Img/favicons-sprite32.png?v=4adbb2dba2cc

Comment: Happens on me too. All site icons offset are off.

Comment: @Warcupine It also works correctly on a Retina display.

Comment: To solve this, y'all get a Retina display ...

Comment: @rene Ha, look at that. Drag the window to the high dpi display and it fixes itself. Drag it back and it breaks again.

Comment: Also works on Stack Overflow in dark mode.  Suggested fix: launch dark mode network-wide ;-)

Comment: About the time this question was posted, it started doing this for me on my inbox icons. Weirdly the Favicons are just fine, normal normal. Brave, up to date. No repro on either phenomenon with chrome.

Comment: This happens every time a new site is added, see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/379726/stack-exchange-site-icons-displaying-incorrectly-in-hot-network-questions and https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/299205/wrong-icons-in-the-hot-network-questions-column. After a few days all mirrors will have synchronized the sprite file and the icons will be back to normal.

Comment: @Marijn That used to happen, yes - but we didn't add a new site this time. We think we've identified the issue and should hopefully have a fix out soon.

Comment: Oddly enough, I don't see the problem on MSE, but on my other sites, I do, including SU and SO.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin Still? it should be fixed at this point. :)

Comment: Just went back to being fine for me (inbox). @JeffZeitlin

Comment: I fail to understand what the edited clarification contributed to a perfectly comprehensible title. Why make a self explanatory title longer and clumsier? That the error was not caused by the addition of a new site should be *in* the answer, if indeed it was the culprit. I get that Catija's first comment suggested it might have been that. But when staff has explained what happened, fixed the error, that is the end of story.

Comment: If the reason was to prevent it from being closed as a duplicate, surely it would have been better to say so in a preface? And actually include the link to the older bug report.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Sorry about that! We're releasing new site themes (have you checked out [Mechanics.SE](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/) and [Datascience.SE](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/) lately?) and one of our themes had an issue while exporting our icons, they were exactly 1px wider than they should be for light themes.

We've now pushed properly sized icons!

Appreciate the fast reporting.