# Incorrect icon in Hot Network Questions and Communities

Tags: bug, status-completed, hot-questions

Observed at: https://stackoverflow.com/

This issue is present even after a hard refresh.

[image: Example]

Additional Examples:

[image]

[image]

Communities:

[image]

**Update:**

On https://stackoverflow.com/ (not working) my sprites are loaded from https://cdn.sstatic.net/img/favicons-sprite16.png?v=57f32c762460

On https://meta.stackexchange.com/ (working) my sprites are loaded from https://meta.stackexchange.com/content/img/favicons-sprite16.png?v=57f32c762460

Comment: I can't repro. Caching?

Comment: Came here to check for a post on this! Seeing the same issue, on both Chrome and IE, and on other SE's (not just SO). Tried clearing everything and restarting IE but still shows up.

Comment: A new site went live earlier, could be related.

Comment: Definitely not a cache issue. I see the issue after opening the Chrome Dev tools and doing "Empty Cache and Hard Reload"

Comment: Seems like it could be an "off-by one" issue, they seem to be displaying the icon of the next site in alphabetical order, IE scifi.stackexchange.com is displaying security.stackexchange.com

Comment: Should be fixed now. Might need a hard refresh of the page on your end. I can't reproduce this, so... let me know if you still see wrong icons?

Comment: Still no luck for me, I'll wait a day and update tomorrow.

Comment: Happening for me too - I noticed it in my profile. The "meta user" link for Puzzling points to Quantitative Finance (which agrees with the "off-by-one issue" hypothesis).

Comment: @Adam happens for at least two people (for me it's fine), maybe [tag:status-norepro] is better fit if you're out of ideas how to fix it?

Comment: This is also happening for me from my home PC. If there are geographically distributed servers, both my home and office are in the Chicago area

Comment: I believe I'm seeing the same thing, except in the reputation changes - the SciFi site is indeed showing as Security.  I'm also in Chicago.

Comment: [Also seeing the same thing](https://i.imgur.com/PmGZd4s.jpg), it's not all sites just a select few for whatever reason.

Comment: The CSS background-position and background-image is the same on both the displays-wrong and displays-right sites, it seems to be the image itself that's returning the wrong thing.  The image URL includes `?v=57f32c762460` which I'd've assumed meant version and was meant to avoid caching issues.

Comment: I have the [same issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZAc27.png). Screenshot from 2017-11-28 2150 GMT on PPCG.

Comment: Also, this has happened before: [1](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/299205/286319), [2](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13556/site-icons-being-messed-up)

Comment: @AdamLear This is still not working for me, I have added additional information to the question.

Comment: I noticed this yesterday, too, and it's still there this morning.  https://i.imgur.com/3ldU09z.png It's kind of funny seeing a comment about being under the Imperius Curse being tagged with the security.stackexchange.com shield.  At first I thought it was a new virus.

Comment: Same issue here... noticed it yesterday, still happening as of now. I checked on several different sites (SO, Puzzling, U&L, Arqade) and all are affected. Oddly, though, seems fine on this site and Meta SO.

Comment: Same issue here, and like @glibdud, I noticed it first yesterday, and still happening as of now.  I notice it mainly in my global inbox, where every message (home site math.se)  is accompanied by a another site's icon.

Comment: This looks fixed as of today.