# Why are the icons in the Hot Network Questions scrambled?

Tags: bug, hot-questions

For the past few days, the icons in the Hot Network Question bar have been wrong. Some are okay, but others are not, which makes me think maybe an index is shifted somewhere. It looks like this was a problem before ([Wrong icons in the "hot network questions" column](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/299205/wrong-icons-in-the-hot-network-questions-column)) but it seems to be occurring again.

For example, right now I see the following icon/site pairings:

1. WorldBuilding icon -> Workplace site
2. MotorVehicles icon -> MathOverflow site
3. Writing icon -> WorldBuilding site
4. Skeptics icon -> Sitecore site
5. Physics icon -> Photos site
6. Security icon -> Scify site (kind of my favorite mistake actually)
7. SuperUser icon -> Stats site

It looks like things in the letter M onwards get messed up. Magneto site shows an "MA" icon, which I think is right (but I'm not positive).

This is happening on Windows, Linux, and Android (website). Using both Firefox and Chrome. I see it on most of the sites (Physics is my home, where the list above came from), although it looks like it's okay on this site. Clicking on a random site (Sitecore), it is wrong there too.

This is a screenshot of the problem:

[image: Scrambled icons]